# Carrierwave gem Secure File Path Cannot read filepath error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, image-uploading

I tried to follow the 'Secure Upload' in carrier wave which is a bit confusing because I have customized the file path and all a bit. When I try to run the app, I get 'Cannot read file' error.

Here's the route :

```
match "/upload_files/:tenant_id/:model/:mount_as/:id/:basename.:extension" => "documents#download",via: [:get, :post] 

class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
"upload_files/#{model.tenant_id}/#model.class.to_s.underscore}/#mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

end
end

carrierwave.rb initializer :

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.permissions = 0600
  config.directory_permissions = 0700
  config.root = Rails.root
end
```

documents controller:`

```
def download
  path = request.fullpath
  send_file path
end
```

got the error

ActionController::MissingFile in DocumentsController#download
Cannot read file /upload_files/1/hoshin_attachment/image/3/support3_HoshinUserStatusReports_08_14_2015.pdf
Please help me to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

CarrierWave seems to compute paths using a **root** variable and the uploader store_dir.
I wanted to store my files in a private folder under Rails.root.
To setup the root:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb

# Uploader settings
CarrierWave.root = Rails.root.to_s
CarrierWave::Uploader::Base.root = Rails.root.to_s
```

To setup the store_dir:

```
# In your uploader class definition
def store_dir
  "private/your_app/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```

Since files are not longer in the public folder, they require actions in controller to show and download. Lets assume the column for the uploaded file is named *uploaded_file*:

```
# In some controller
# you have to ensure @document initialize with a before_action filter


def show_file
  send_file @document.unsigned_file.path,
            filename: @document.uploaded_file_identifier,
            disposition: :inline,
            type: @document.uploaded_file.content_type
end

def download_file
  send_file @document.unsigned_file.path,
            filename: @document.uploaded_file_identifier,
            disposition: :attachment,
            type: @document.uploaded_file.content_type
end
```